How to isolate server traffic using VLANs with limited router capabilities?
I am a beginner in networking and I currently have the following network setup:
Main Router: Huawei Optixstar with only 1 VLAN for internet access (no option to create new VLANs). It handles lan and wifi access.
DSL Router: Xiaomi configured as a bridge to manage LAN and Wi-Fi. It is connected to main router via łan.
Active Switch: TP-Link TL-SG105E (Layer 2 switching). Connected to main router via lan.
2x Wi-Fi Repeaters: Xiaomi devices. Connected to main router via wi-fi.
End Devices: Various devices connected via Wi-Fi to main router, access points or DSL router.
Problem Description:
I have a server connected to the switch that has port forwarding set up on the router for HTTP and HTTPS traffic. I want to isolate the server traffic to a separate VLAN so that external access via these open ports doesn’t allow unwanted access to my other devices on the network via server.
Current Problem:
I cannot create a new VLAN on the main router.
Proposed Solution:
I plan to treat the main router as an internet access point. Here are the steps I intend to follow:

Disable Wi-Fi on the main router.
Connect only one device (a VLAN-capable router) directly to the main router.
Enable Wi-Fi on the new router and create two VLANs: one for the server and another for the rest of the devices connected to the switch. Handle them on the switch, to route traffic from seprate vlans to server and rest of devices.
Ensure that other devices connected to the new router operate on the VLAN of the main router. Connected via lan(DSL router) and wi-fi (repeaters and end devices).

Question
Once I set up routing for the VLANs on the new router to route all vlans to 1 vlan of main router, to get internet access will the isolation work as intended?

Welcome to Superuser. Please limit your post to a single question. Pick one of the questions you have here and remove the others.

Unfortunately even the most capable level 3 switch by default allows individual VLANs to communicate so there is little to no chance a less than capable router or switch to support blocking VLANs communication between VLANs

I want to buy a good new router that supports VLAN segmentation, and use it to separate traffic into VLANs, then direct that traffic to the VLAN of the main router, to which it will be connected. The switch I have is active switch that supports traffic segregation between VLANs. Won't this isolate the traffic?

I suppose that if i route separate vlans via lan ports to end unmanaged devices they will work only on selected vlan. So how can they communicate between each other? I am afrais about routing all vlans to main vlan of main router at the end but maybe i am wrong.

Are you sure the huawei router is an actual router ? A quick search led me to a product page for a ONT (optical networkterminal). If it only has one ethernet port, its likely not a router and something else in your network is doing the routing. That router will most likely have VLAN support. @Ramhound no idea what L3 switches you normally work with, but ive always been able to fully isolate VLANs on them.

@Silbee - Ubiquiti devices; by default allow VLAN communication I didn’t say it can’t be blocked I just said by default they can communicate with one another

I have Huawei OptiXstar EG8145X6 with configured 1 vlan by internet provider i can not manage them. I Heard that when provider switch IT to bridge mode, what is possibile and provide mi auth data i can manager network on new router connected via lan to Huawei.

Once I set up routing for the VLANs on the new router to route all vlans to 1 vlan of main router, to get internet access will the isolation work as intended? AFAIK, VLAN isolation really means that the router would have stateful packet filtering / firewall at layer 3 that drops initiating traffics from one VLAN to another (similar to filtering that drops such traffics from "WAN" to "LAN" / V"LAN"s and can be found on even many of the cheapest home router). As long as the router adopts such approach for VLAN isolation, you don't need to worry about "upper" / "outer" devices on its "WAN".
